# how to scrape amazon deals page in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, command-line, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to **scrape** amazon deal page by python and beautiful soup but when run the code I don't get any result but when trying the code on any another page in amazon I get results

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0',
           'referer': 'https://www.amazon.com/'
           }
s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)
r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
for x in soup.find_all('span',{'class','a-declarative'}):
    print(x.text + "\n")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: Have you done any debugging whatsoever?

Comment: no debug but with searching, I found that this page use js in display products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you visit that page in your browser, the page makes additional requests to get more information, it then updates the first page with that information. In your case, the url https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn is just a template, and when loaded it makes additional requests to get the deal information to populate the template.

Amazon is a popular site and people have made many web scrapers for it. Check [this one out.](https://github.com/tducret/amazon-scraper-python). If it doesn't do what you need just google `github amazon scraper` and you will get many options.

If you still want to code a scraper yourself, start reading up on `selenium`. It is a python package that simulates a web browser, allowing you to load a web page and all its additional requests before scraping.